# AdvancedDatagrid does not display grouped data

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, advanceddatagrid, flex4.6

I am trying to display grouped data in AdvancedDatagrid but the data does not show up. When I specify the dataprovider without the grouping collection I am able to see the data. Is there something wrong with this code?

```
<mx:AdvancedDataGrid id="dgAssetStatus" width="100%" height="85%" initialize="gc.refresh();">
    <mx:dataProvider>
        <mx:GroupingCollection2 id="gc" source="{_list}">
            <mx:grouping>
                <mx:Grouping label="asset_name">
                    <mx:GroupingField name="asset_name"/>
                </mx:Grouping>                  
            </mx:grouping>
        </mx:GroupingCollection2>
    </mx:dataProvider>
    <mx:columns>
        <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn dataField="asset_name" headerText="Asset"/> 
        <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn dataField="status" headerText="Status"/>
    </mx:columns>
</mx:AdvancedDataGrid>
```

Comment: What's in the GroupingCollection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out an answer to this question myself. I was not able to see any data in the ADG since the `refresh()` method was being called before the `_list` ArrayCollection was populated. I just had to move the refresh call to fix this issue.